# Getting latitude and longitude from address does not work (Error at InputStream)

Tags: android, google-maps, httpurlconnection, inputstreamreader

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of a place with the following code:

```
public LatLng findAddress(String place) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        String googleMapUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                + place + "&sensor=false";

        URL url = new URL(googleMapUrl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
        String a = "";
        StringBuilder sb = jsonResults;
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            JSONArray resultJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject before_geometry_jsonObj = resultJsonArray
                    .getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject geometry_jsonObj = before_geometry_jsonObj
                    .getJSONObject("geometry");
            JSONObject location_jsonObj = geometry_jsonObj
                    .getJSONObject("location");
            String lat_helper = location_jsonObj.getString("lat");
            double lat = Double.valueOf(lat_helper);
            String lng_helper = location_jsonObj.getString("lng");
            double lng = Double.valueOf(lng_helper);
            return new LatLng(lat, lng);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new LatLng(0,0);
        }

    }
```

But when I run it, it goes to the catch-part (right after the

```
 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
```

part.) 
Even after some time revising the code, I do not seem to have found the reason behind this phenomenon. 
(the reason why I do not use the GeoCoder service is because it is not stable, and  requires a reboot on every device I have tested on)

Comment: Could you please post the error stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile I have solved it.
I got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, I should not have run a network call on the Main thread. Thank you all for your help.